# Spring Batch with AMQP RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I'd like to use String Batch to get the data from RabbitMQ / AMQP. 
I want to load 100 messages (or if 100 doesn't come, the number of messsages camed after some timeout) and then put it into the list. 
I have a RabbitMQ working, i'd just like to get the data from it in packages per 100 and concentrate it to the list.

I have read about Spring Batch, i found that this can read from files (ex. CSV) using `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader`. 
But I dont know how to read from a Rabbit Queue? Or is it even possible?

Kind Regards,

Rafał

Comment: Is Spring Batch negotiable? If yes, consider Mule, which has an AMQP connector and can aggregate messages for you.

Comment: yes, spring batch is negotiable. Mule is ok, but is too heavy for my project.

Comment: Define heavy. Seriously. Is it the number of dependencies? Not sure Spring Batch has less when you embed Mule in your app and bring only the transports/module JARs you need. Is it another kind of "heaviness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Spring-AMQP?

- http://www.springsource.org/spring-amqp
- http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/04/amqp-messaging-with-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Spring Batch AMQP ItemReader / ItemWriter implementation.
https://dzone.com/articles/batch-processing-with-spring-batch-and-amqp-easier

Comment: This link is no longer active now

Comment: changed the link.